# Org-mode: customize delimiter for horizontal line in tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table

The default column-delimiter for horizontal lines in tables is a `+` sign. How to change it to vertical bar `|`?

Currently, it looks likes this:

```
|---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |   |
|---+---+---+---+---|
|   |   |   |   |   |
```

But I want it do be like this:

```
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   |   |   |   |
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   |   |   |   |
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   |   |   |   |
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without changes to the code. If that is true and If you do change the code for yourself, you will make it impossible to share org documents with anybody else. You will also be saddled with a continuing maintenance problem, since you will have forked the upstream repo, unless you can convince the maintainers to make the change upstream (that is highly unlikely: there will be lots of current users who will object).

Comment: @NickD Thanks. That kind sucks. I would imagine such delimiter is customizable.

Comment: As I said, that would make it so you couldn't share documents with anybody else unless they set the hypothetical option to exactly the same thing as you.

Comment: It might be possible to use text faces to just change the appearance of the delimiter in your buffers if this is simply an aesthetic wish.

Comment: I wanted to follow the `Markdown` syntax for tables. Using the org-table delimiter mess up when I try to visualize it on GitHub for example.

Comment: You might try converting the document using `pandoc`: something like `pandoc -f org -t gfm <file>.org -o <file>.md` should do it. Exporting to markdown might also be worth trying, but ISTR the `ox-md` exporter is very rudimentary.

Comment: @rkioji I don't use GitHub much but I remember reading it supports both Markdown (for files with extension `.md`) and Org Mode (for extension `.org`). Are you saying that it doesn't understand Org Mode's table syntax in a `.org` file or are you pasting an Org Mode table into a Markdown file?

Comment: @Omar I am pasting an org-mode table in a markdown file.

Comment: @Omar Since GitHub does not understand the `+` delimiter, I have to manually replace (with a script) them before publishing on GitHub.

Comment: @rkioji Well, there's your problem! It's not just tables that won't work: sections, italics, etc., all differ. (It feels weird to single out tables when everything is different.) You need to export to markdown, or start using GitHub's Org Mode support (by simply changing the file extension to `.org`).

Comment: @Omar Sorry, I think I was not clear. I write all my docs using conventional Markdown format. Only when I wanna create tables I use org-mode in that region, because org-mode-table is fantastic. But since the syntax for tables in Markdown does not support '+' I have to manually replace them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
(defun toggle-table-org/gfm ()
  "Toggle table at point between Org Mode and GitHub-Flavored Markdown syntaxes."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((table-end (progn
                       (markdown-forward-paragraph)
                       (point))))
      (markdown-backward-paragraph)
      (while (search-forward "-+-" table-end t)
        (replace-match "-|-"))
      (while (search-forward "-|-" table-end t)
        (replace-match "-+-")))))
```

By the way, I specifically chose to call the syntax "GitHub-Flavored Markdown", because table syntax varies a lot in different types of Markdown.

The function uses `markdown-forward-paragraph` which you have if you are editing your markdown in `markdown-mode`. If you don't use `markdown-mode`, let me know and we'll figure out how to implement it then.

Comment: I do use `markdown-mode`. I wouldn't want to have to call this script every time. But I guess this is the best solution we can get since there is no way to replace the delimiter for `org-mode`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is already something you do everytime: yank the table. You could modify the above function to yank the converted version instead.